# Salesforce queuable implementation

Tags: apex, api, callout

So i was checking the documentation of Queuable jobs, but I don't clearly understand the relationship between govern limits and every job that you can chain or create.

My first question is, considering that in every transaction you are up to 100 callouts, it means that every new job I create its a new transaction itself?, and it reboots the governor limits for this new job? Does that mean, that i would be able to do 100callouts for every Job?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider accepting this as the answer if it answers your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion is due to your understanding of Apex Transaction.
When you will consider each instance of queuable job as a single transaction, all limits will be clear to you.

Please find below answers :

1. considering that in every transaction you are up to 100 callouts, it means that every new job I create its a new transaction itself?

- Yes , every call to `System.enqueueJob(new AsyncExecutionExample())`; is a new transaction.

2. it reboots the governor limits for this new job?

- Yes , if by new job you mean call to `System.enqueueJob(new AsyncExecutionExample())`

3. Does that mean, that i would be able to do 100 callouts?

- Yes , 100 callouts per Apex transaction.
  Please refer Apex transaction definition [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction.htm)

Apex Governor limits : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

Comment: Thank you @rohit, you made it clear! I was a lit bit confused about apex transaction! Have a good day!

Comment: Thank you accepting as the answer !